# extract multiple sublists of different size into different data.frames one for each sublist

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I want to extract multiple sublists of different size into different data.frames one dataframe for each sublist.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

I tried:

```
    extract_one <- function(x) {
  data.frame(dat[[1]]) }

out <- lapply(dat, extract_one).
```

My idea was to extract the first part of the list and then leveraging lapply to do it for every sublist. 
Obviously does not work.
Any help would be highly appreciated! 
Regards

Comment: `out <- lapply(dat, data.frame)`?

Comment: by sublist do you mean column?

Comment: You will get further if you replace `dat[[1]]` with just `x`